# Azure Functions - StorageBlob Trigger method signature using CloudBlockBlob not Stream

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Creating Azure Functions targeting .Net Standard 2.0 using Visual Studio 2017.

Using the Add New Azure Function wizard, a blob trigger method is successfully created with the following method signature.

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("attachments-collection/{name}")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
```

This method compiles and works fine.

However, we want to be able access the metadata connected to the CloudBlockBlob being saved to storage, which as far as I know is not possible using a stream. Other answers on this site such as ([Azure Function Blob Trigger CloudBlockBlob binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384959/azure-function-blob-trigger-cloudblockblob-binding)) suggest you can bind to a CloudBlockBlob instead of a Stream and access the metadata that way. But the suggested solution does not compile in latest version of Azure Functions.

Microsoft's online documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---usage) also seems to confirm that it is possible to bind the trigger to a CloudBlockBlob rather than a Stream, but gives no example of the syntax.

Could someone please clarify the exact syntax required to enable Azure Function Blob storage trigger to bind to a CloudBlockBlob instead of the standard Stream?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set `FileAccess.ReadWrite` in the Blob Attribute as parameter? According to the docs you have to.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input---usage

Comment: In case you get  compilation error. Can you please post the message here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is capture the CloudBlockBlob that triggers the function. For this, I believe I need to use the BlobTrigger attribute not the Blob attribute. When I try to set FileAccess.ReadWrite in BlobTrigger attribute, there is a compilation error "'BlobTriggerAttribute does not contain a constructor that takes two arguments".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `CloudBlockBlob` does work, we don't need `FileAccess.ReadWrite` as it's BlobTrigger instead of Blob input or output.

```
public static Task Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")]CloudBlockBlob blob, string name, ILogger log)
```

**Update for Can't bind BlobTrigger to CloudBlockBlob**

There's an issue tracking [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3784), Function SDK has some problem integrating with `WindowsAzure.Storge` >=v9.3.2. So just remove any `WindowsAzure.Storage` package reference, Function SDK references v9.3.1 internally by default.

Comment: Jerry - thanks. I've tried exactly this, and everything compiles okay. However, when I publish to Azure, the function is never triggered when a blob is added to storage. (It works fine if the blob is Stream in the signature not CloudBlockBlob).

Comment: @Nick So with `Stream` as type, you can see function triggered after publishing? How do you check whether the function is triggered? On my side, it works as expected. You could go to kudu(`https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host` to see logs.

Comment: yes, the function is triggered with Stream as type. I am checking the function's output using the Azure portal logging stream (FunctionApps -> Click on function -> Expand 'Logs' at bottom of screen)

Comment: @Nick I see, sometimes the log panel may lose connection to logging stream. Could you try to visit kudu(follow my suggestion above)? Of if you have configured Application Insights, you can click on function -> click its `Monitor` blade to check execution results.

Comment: Using kudu, I can see from the log that the function with the CloudBlockBlob signature fails to load correctly with the following error "2018-12-17T09:11:15.466 [Error] Error indexing method 'MyFunctionName.Run'"

Comment: Error details is : Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException : Error indexing method 'MyFunctionName.Run'' ---> System.InvalidOperationException : Can't bind BlobTrigger to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'

Comment: Other functions in the same Function App are loaded okay, including one with the Stream type signature (which works okay and shows up in log operating correctly)

Comment: Is this an Azure Storage version issue? I am using Nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage (9.3.2)

Comment: @Nick You are totally right, remove it should be enough, function sdk has built-in reference for v9.3.1. See my update.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Jerry Liu's s insights, this problem has been solved.

Method:
Use the default storage package for Azure Storage that is installed when you create a new Function App

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage (3.0.1)

This installs dependency

> WindowsAzure.Storage (9.3.1)

Then both of the following method signatures will run correctly

```
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
```

and

```
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")]CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
```

Comment: how to copy CloudBlockBlob into Stream?